# How to create listeners with javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, callback, listener

I need to create a main class `animal`, then have two sub classes inherit properties from `animal` which are `cat` and `dog`, then I was to make multiple objects (multiple cat's and dog's) inherit from the class `cat` and `dog` (I read it's not really a class but it behaves as a class).

The multiple objects (cat1, mycat, tomcat, dog1, mydog, topdog) need to be able to talk and listen to each  other. When talking I would have them just alert or print a text line. What I am having trouble with is the listening part. I want the individual myDog to print out "dog heard cat" when myCat makes a sound. This is the code I have so far.

```
var animal = function (name, sound, listen) {
    var f = 0;
    this.name = name; // this.prop means prop is public var.
    this.sound = sound;
    this.listen = listen;
    this.makesound = function () {
        alert(this.sound);
    }
    this.listen = function () {
        alert(this.name + "heard that");
    }
    return this;
};

/*--------------- inheritance -----------------------------------*/
var cat = function () {

    this.name = name;
    this.sound = 'meow';
    return this;
};
cat.prototype = new animal();

function dog(name) {
    dog.sound = 'woof';
    dog.name = name;
    return this;
};
dog.prototype = new animal();

/*-------- different kinda dogs/cats ----------------------------*/
var myCat = new cat();
var myDog = new dog();
var tomCat = new cat();
var bigDog = new dog();
/*-----------------------*/
```

I think I'm supposed to use an `if` statement, I heard I can use like a
`if (callback) callback{}` but my attempts to implement something like that are failing. I'm BRAND new to javascript only been learning it last couple days. Any help or assistance would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do all animals hear when another animal makes a sound or does an animal make a sound for a specific animal to hear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it... I'd set those who are listening. `listening` is an optional parameter when you create a new object. You can also change those who are listening after creation using `setListening`. `listening` in this case will just be an array of objects that have a `name` property.

Also, I fixed some issues, you either didn't have "name" or weren't setting it in any case.

http://jsfiddle.net/n9xCM/

```
var animal = function (name, sound, listening) {
    var f = 0;
    this.name = name; // this.prop means prop is public var.
    this.sound = sound;
    this.listening = listening;
    this.makesound = function () {
        alert(this.sound);
        this.listen();
    }
    this.setListening = function (listening) {
        this.listening = listening;
    }
    this.listen = function () {
        console.log("in listen ("+this.listening.length+")");
        for (var i = 0; i < this.listening.length; i++) {
            alert(this.listening[i].name + " heard that");
        }
    }
    return this;
};

/*--------------- inheritance -----------------------------------*/
var cat = function (name, listening) {
    this.name = name;
    this.listening = listening;
    this.sound = 'meow';
    return this;
};
cat.prototype = new animal();

function dog(name, listening) {
    this.sound = 'woof';
    this.listening = listening;
    this.name = name;
    return this;
};
dog.prototype = new animal();

/*-------- different kinda dogs/cats ----------------------------*/
var myDog = new dog("mydog");
var myCat = new cat("mycat", [myDog]);
var bigDog = new dog("buster");
var tomCat = new cat("tommy", [bigDog]);
myCat.makesound(); //meow - mydog heard that
bigDog.setListening([myDog, myCat, tomCat]);
bigDog.makesound(); //woof - mydog/mycat/tommy heard that

/*-----------------------*/
```

Comment: Thanks guys if I had more rep I would upvote! you two this heled a lot. Also I can google observer pattern and figure it out that helps :)

Comment: Hey Ryan, you can still select an answer by clicking the check mark under the up/down votes

Comment: oh I didn't know that okay, really i like them both though!

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern for that, the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). When an animal makes a sound the other animals get notified (they 'listen' to it).

```
this.listen = function(otherAnimal) 
{
    alert(this.name + "heard " + otherAnimal.name);
}
```

So the `makeSound` function has to call the `listen` method of all animals that can 'listen' to the sound. To do that it has to know those, i.e. have a list of them, or if it's only one, have a reference to that.

```
function makeSound() {
    alert(this.sound);
     for (var i = 0; i < this.listening.length; i++) {
        this.listening[i].listen(this);
    }
    // OR this.listening.listen(this); if it can only be one other animal
}
```

`listening` could come in as an argument via constructor or method.

P.S.: Never use an `if` or `switch` to make decisions based on a type. That's what OOP is for.