# Ext JS events/callbacks, object communication for newb

Tags: events, extjs

I'm a self studying student who is brand new to to both javascript and ExtJs.

What I am trying to do is create a main class animal, then have two sub classes inherit properties/methods from animal. Those are cat and dog... then I would like to make multiple objects (multiple cat's and dog's) inherit from the class cat and dog. The multiple objects, cat1, mycat, cat2, dog1, mydog, topdog etc... were supposed to be able to talk and listen to each other.

when the cat1, mycat etc talk, it's just alert (stuff), and when that happens the  dog alerts "mydog heard that".

I did this in javascript already with help from the community ([How to create listeners with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391549/javascript-callbacks-w-inheritance))

I want to do this now using ExtJS too. This is what I have so far

```
Ext.define('animal', {
    extend: 'Ext.util.Observable',
    constructor: function(config)
    {
        this.name = config.name;
        this.addEvents({'makesound' :true});
        this.listeners = config.listeners;
        //animal.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    makesound: function() 
    {
        alert(this.sound);
        this.fireEvent('makesound'); // this is wrong isn't it?
                                     // I was thinking that the make sound  
                                     // would trigger the event makesound                             
    }
});


//var cat = Ext.create('animal');
//var dog = new animal;

//cat.makesound();
//dog.makesound();

Ext.define('cat', {
    extend: 'animal',
    name: name,
    sound: 'meow'
});
Ext.define('dog', {
    extend: 'animal',
    name: name,
    sound: 'woof'
});

var myCat = new cat({
    name: 'myCat'});

var myDog = new dog({
    name:'mydog',
    listeners: {    
        makesound: function() {
            alert('mydog heard that');
        }
    }
});

myCat.makesound();
myDog.fireEvent('makesound');  //
```

What I really want is for mycat to make sound, then mydog automatically hear that makesound (the 'meow') and alert my dog heard that. In extJS though. Any help or advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have your class definitions set up correctly, you just need to add listeners to the correct instances:

```
var myCat = new Cat({ name: 'myCat' });
var myDog = new Dog({ name: 'myDog' });

myCat.on('makesound', function() {
    myDog.makesound();
});
```

The way you have it currently set up, your listener is on `myDog`, meaning that your "mydog heard that" will show up when `myDog` makes a sound, not `myCat`.

One other note: you should always name your classes with a capital letter (use `Animal` instead of `animal`).